# como ler um arquivo txt e tranformá-lo em uma matriz, sem utilizar a função split()?

Tags: python, txt

fiz um código usando a função split, e ficou dessa maneira:

```
matriz = []
f = open("dados.txt", "r")
for line in f:
  linha = (line.split(','))
  matriz.append(linha)
```

porém preciso chegar a mesma matriz sem utilizar a função `split(),`  há alguma maneira?

Comment: Qual o problema de usar a biblioteca pandas para isso? `matriz = pandas.read_csv("dados.txt")`

Comment: Só por curiosidade, por que não pode usar `split`?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a biblioteca `csv` nativa do Python

```py
import csv
with open('dados.txt') as csvfile:
  spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  matrix = [line for line in spamreader]
```

O código acima foi inspirado no Exemplo dado na própria documentação:
https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/csv.html#csv.reader